# Solving an integral (using Cauchy contour integral?)

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

I need to solve this integral: 
\begin{equation}
f(t)=\int_0^\infty x^2 \sqrt x \left( e^{a x} -1\right)^{-1/2} \frac{e^{i(b-x)t}-1}{b-x} dx
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are real, positive constants.

I was thinking Cauchy contour integral might help..

Any help/advice is welcome!

Comment: Where did this integral come from?